Environment taking left or right justification argument
I have the following environment that originally utilised flushright.  I want to adapt this to accept both flushleft or flushright depending on an environment argument.
Somehow I need flush#1 to become either flushleft or flushright
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \justr_ditura:n
  {
    \str_case:nnF {#1}
      {
        {l}     {left}
        {L}     {left}
        {r}     {right}
        {R}     {right}
        {left}  {left}
        {right} {right}
      }
    {left}  % default for non-matching case.

  }

\NewDocumentEnvironment {ditura} { O{r} }

  %% Begin Code
  {
    \begin {flush#1}
      \begin{tabular} { @{} l@{} }
  }

  %% End Code
  {
      \end{tabular}
    \end {flush#1}
  }

  \ExplSyntaxOff

  \begin{document}

  \begin (ditura}
    Likku Cirillu \\
    Peppu Grillu  \\
    Something and Something
  \end {ditura}

  \end{document}


you have been told more than once to show a complete example. I will vote to close this question as unclear.

Do you want an example that works ?  What I am trying to do is broken.

Your code almost works: Replace flush#1 by flush\justr_ditura:n{#1}.
Besides, there is a typo in your sample code: replace (ditura} by {ditura}.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \justr_ditura:n
  {
    \str_case:nnF {#1}
      {
        {l}     {left}
        {L}     {left}
        {r}     {right}
        {R}     {right}
        {left}  {left}
        {right} {right}
      }
    {left}  % default for non-matching case.

  }

\NewDocumentEnvironment {ditura} { O{r} }
  
  %% Begin Code
  {
    \begin {flush\justr_ditura:n{#1}}
      \begin{tabular} { @{} l@{} }
  }

  %% End Code
  {
      \end{tabular}
    \end {flush\justr_ditura:n{#1}}
  }

  \ExplSyntaxOff

  \begin{document}

  \begin {ditura}[r]
    Likku Cirillu \\
    Peppu Grillu  \\
    Something and Something
  \end {ditura}

\end{document}

